# Link to submit moderation election nomination is invisible

Tags: bug, design

As per the title, I had a hard time finding it. The link should be underlined as everywhere else.

[image]

---

[image: fds]

Comment: Sklivvz has clicked on it. Before you do that, it is even more obscure.

Comment: I can't edit questions in meta, **at all** now? :( I was going to add the screenshot to what it looks like before clicking on the link. http://i.stack.imgur.com/Cqjnj.png <-- in case anyone wants to edit it in.